# Failed to open stream when file is clearly there and accessible by URL

Tags: php

I'm getting an "unexplainable" error on this line:

```
require_once "../Http/Request.php";
```

Error is failed to open stream, file doesn't exist.

The file is in a directory in the parent folder called "Http". The file is called "Request.php".

I can access it directly by typing the absolute path into my browser, so I can confirm it is indeed uploaded to my server, in the correct folder.

At this point I have to rule out the possibility that the warning/fatal error is accurate and trying to figure out where the problem could be coming from.

**Which steps do you suggest to start debugging this?**

```
Google
   ¦_____ Auth
   ¦        ¦______ Abstract.php    (<- this is the file requiring Request.php)
   ¦
   ¦_____ Http
            ¦_____ Request.php
```

Comment: Hint: `echo getcwd();`

Comment: Where is the file that calls this code?

Comment: Post some kind of tree folder

Comment: @Juicy is google the root folder ? If no, can you give me the full path starting from the root

Comment: try to use namespace.

Comment: Not the actual "Google" and not the root of my website either. It's a subfolder on my website, that has several subfolders itself.

Comment: Try to do this: /subfolder1/subfolder2/.../Request.php Don't forget the **first** slash

Comment: Thanks all, @zerkms had the solution to debug this. The file requiring Request.php was itself included in another file, and that file apparently messed up the relative path by going up in the tree. Zerkms is you want some points you can put that as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> I can access it directly by typing the absolute path into my browser,
>   so I can confirm it is indeed uploaded to my server, in the correct
>   folder.

Here’s your problem: You are conflating browser URL path to server file path. And since you say you can access it directly via your browser, then it’s not a file system permissions issue since the web server itself can read the file.

So instead I am going to chalk this up to headache inducing relative path issues. So I would recommend getting rid of this:

```
 require_once "../Http/Request.php";
```

And instead just set a base path manually in a config file & don’t worry about it—relative paths—ever again.

So as far as a file base path goes, you should explicitly set a `$BASE_PATH` like this:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/full/path/to/your/codebase/here/';
```

If you don’t know what your file system base path is, just place this line of code in your PHP code; like `index.php`:

```
echo "Your path is: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "<br />";
```

Then load that page. Somewhere near the top will be this text:

> Your path is: /full/path/to/your/codebase/here/

Then with that set you can change your code to be something like this:

And then set your `require_once` like this:

```
require_once $BASE_PATH . "Http/Request.php";
```

Some might say you should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or even `dirname(__FILE__)` directly with the implication being that you can simplify code portability that way. But the way file paths are set for installs can vary so it just never works well & the chances of you getting snagged on an odd server quirk is high.

It’s always best to just to manually set a `$BASE_PATH` in a config file when you move code than deal with the headaches caused by PHP constants like `$_SERVER` not being consistent between installs, setups & configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that

```
require_once "../Http/Request.php";
```

includes the path relative to the current working directory. Which is not guaranteed to be equal to the current file directory.

What you presumably need is

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/Http/Request.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to check permission on this folder.

If folder has not read permission then give permission for execute and read.

to one level up from google directory structure and type

```
ls -ltr
```

First column of result is permission access for google folder and itmust be like

> drwxr-xr-x

if not like this then You have to change this by folloing command:

```
chmod 755 Google
```

Hope this help.